# Python Tkinter login page, loop and .CSV

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, authentication

I’m trying to create a login page using python and tkinter. I have most of it done, I just need some help with the verification. I have the usernames and passwords stored in a .CSV. The program works but my while loop is wrong. It correctly verifies the user’s username and password but because of the loop it sends a messagebox saying it failed then another saying it was successful (depends on how many users I have stored). Also the elif that checks if nothing has been entered causes the messagebox to close and keep popping up. Thanks for the help.

```
    def verification(self):
    username = username_verify.get()
    password = password_verify.get()

    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)

    import csv
    with open('Users.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        database = []
        for row in reader:
            database.append(dict(username=row['username'], password=row['password']))

    logged_in = False
    while not logged_in:
        for row in database:
            username_file = row['username']
            password_file = row['password']

            if (username_file == username and password_file == password):
                logged_in = True
                tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Success", "Login successful")
                root.destroy()
                import SecondWindow
            elif username == "" or password == "":
                tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Username or password not entered, please retry!")   
            else:
                tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Username or password not recognised, please retry!")
```

Comment: Can you show sample `'Users.csv'` content?

Comment: You loop through every user and password inside the while loop. What is that for?

Comment: You show an error that the password isn’t correct for every line in the Users.csv file that isn’t the correct username and password. This causes (part) of the erroneous messages. You only want to show an error if none of the lines in Users.csv match username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Does this fix it? (Trying from mobile phone, so I haven’t been able to test it)

```
def verification(self):

    username = username_verify.get()
    password = password_verify.get()

    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)

    import csv
    with open('Users.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        database = []
        for row in reader:
            database.append(dict(username=row['username'], password=row['password']))

    logged_in = False
    while not logged_in:
        if username == "" or password == "":
            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Username or password not entered, please retry!")  
        for row in database:
            username_file = row['username']
            password_file = row['password']

            if (username_file == username and password_file == password):
                logged_in = True
                tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Success", "Login successful")
                root.destroy()
                import SecondWindow
                break

        if not logged_in:
            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Username or password not recognised, please retry!")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it doesnt fix the problem

Comment: Do you still get the errorbox that no username or password is entered, or some other problem? Does `username = username_verify.get()` and `password = password_verify.get()` give the correct (entered) values?